# Powershell check if file exists in multiple folders and Output

Tags: powershell

I have a few hundred folders that look like this:

```
\\\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\LCTS

\\\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\GBSS

\\\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\TRGS
```

etc

I need to check them for a specific file e.g. "`Results 20150722New.dat`"

I need to know the folders that do not contain the file, it may be nice if that can be outputted to a file e.g. `log.txt` but its more I need a list of folders that do not contain it.

I have been trying to use Test-Path but am really not getting anywhere

any chance someone could help me make a start on this

Comment: Please post an example of the code that you have tried, an indication of the actual vs expected output and any errors that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

As one time operation you can find names (string) of all directories, that does not contain such file name, using:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\" | 
Where {$_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach { if (-not(Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\Results 20150722New.dat")) {Echo $_.FullName } }
```

Optionally specify -Recurse switch to search folders recursively.

If there's a need to manipulate with results later, I'd prefer to save DirectoryInfo objects to a clollection instead of converting them to strings with Echo cmdlet.

```
$dirs_not_containing_file = @()
$dirs_not_containing_file +=
Get-ChildItem "\\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\" | 
Where {$_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach { if (-not(Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\Results 20150722New.dat")) {$_} }
```

Splitted second statement to multiple lines for readability.

Comment: Thanks this has given me a start, I should have said, I do need to be able to list the folders or part of them e.g. \\uat.xxx.com\FileExport\New Collections\XXXX\ part as there are load in there we are not interested in

Comment: What do you mean by "to list folders"? To create a table of folders and contains / not contains column?